# nodeJS/GitlabCI: How to serve decentralized productive application

Tags: node.js, express, gitlab, next.js

I'm developing a nodeJS application using nextJS and an expressJS application. And I'm using an own gitlab instance for managing the git repository.

But the current application should not be deployed to a webserver at the end, but I need to create decentralized productive application. To make it a bit clearer:

1. Developing the application locally
2. Push application to my remote server
3. My customers should be able to get the productive app code from my remove server
4. Customers will run the application on there local environment - should be able to pull new versions from the remove server

**So the application itself won't run on my remote server, but on the local server of the customers.**

Normaly I would use my CI to test and build the application (which is be done by `npm run build`). Then I build an docker image which I use to run the application on my server. But all that is normaly working on the same server.

In this case I need to build the application and serve it to the customers / the customers should be able to pull the productive code. How can this be done.

Maybe I lose sight of the wood for the trees... and that's why I'm asking for help/hints.

Comment: I don't understand how this is any different from any other company that utilizes software available from a git repo.  Are you in charge of their deployments or just in charge of developing?  Are you asking how to utilize hooks to tell the company to update and deploy their own instances?  Offering you advice on how you might go about this seems too broad.  Please state the workflow that you want and how we can help you solve/implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this and a number of tools you can use as well. You probably want a pipeline similar to the following.

1. Code is developed locally, committed, and pushed to the self-hosted gitlab.
2. GitLab CI, (or any other CI configured) will then run CI of your code.
3. The final step of the CI is to create a "bundle" of your application. This is probably a .zip or similar and this will be pushed to a remote storage location. It is also possible to ensure that this is done only when pushing to specific branches (such as master).

You can use a number of things as your remote storage location, such as some sort of AWS S3 bucket, or something more complex such as [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype) (there are many free alternatives).

You would then want to give your customers access to either this storage location (if you're using something like S3, or Digital Ocean Block Storage, etc), or access to your distribution repository (such as Nexus).

You should be able to generate some sort of SSH key that you can put on your GitLabCI server and use to publish to these places. It should then be a simple case of making a HTTP call to upload a file to the relevant source. This would often be called when everything has been successful, and only for specific branches. For example if all your tests pass and you're on the master branch, zip up all your code and make a HTTP call to push the new zip file to AWS S3 which your customers have access to.

For further ideas, you could make your storage / distribution location into an FTP server if you wanted to, or a local network drive depending on what your needs are for distribution. If you're just dealing with docker for your customers, then I'd suggest building a Docker image and self-hosting a docker registry. Push to that registry after you've built the image, and that would be the end of your CI run.

As a side note, if your customers are using docker you could create a docker image either push it to a registry or export it as a .tar and upload it to a file storage location (S3 for example). This would make things simple for your customers and ensure you control the image creation step (if that's something you want to manage).

[The gitlab ci docs might help you with the specifics of uploading artifacts to various locations.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/job_artifacts.html)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. That's exactly what I was looking for. Just one question: In my gitlab CI I'm running the build. Now I need to get a zip file from that builded files. I guess those are called artifacts, right? Then I would like to upload the zip file to my own ftp server

Comment: If this answer is correct, could you mark is as correct for others in the future? Ti answer your question, yes, you probably want a build step which is something like "package_artifact" which will locate all the files you wish to bundle together, zip them up, and tell GitLabCI that they're an artifact. You might then have a step after which is "publish_artifact" which pushes them to some location like an FTP server.